# how to resize images imported into tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**i  somehow was able to import images but i want to resize those images how can i do that ??? please help me out **

````
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
import random
import tkinter.ttk

from PIL import ImageTk, Image
class Pics(tk.Toplevel):
   def __init__(self, parent):
         super().__init__(parent)
         self.original_frame = parent
         self.geometry("1400x700")
         self.title("Easter Eggs")
         self.configure(background="#ff80ff")

         load = Image.open("788f27edb761cb3e6af9422ece19fcc4.jpg")
         
         render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
         img = Label(self, image = render)
         img.image = render
         img.place(x=1, y=5)

         load = Image.open("op96es9026wy.png")
         render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
         img = Label(self, image = render)
         img.image = render
         img.place(x=2, y=2)```
````

Comment: use `load.resize()`

Comment: there are no errors but there was no effect ,, no change to size of image

Comment: You need to say `load = Image.open("op96es9026wy.png").resize((width,height),Image.ANTIALIAS)`.

Comment: yes thx it worked but can u help me out how can i change the position of the images as i have multiple images but they are starting to overlap

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
load = Image.open("op96es9026wy.png")
resize= load.resize((250, 250),Image.ANTIALIAS)
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize)
img = Label(self, image = render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=2, y=2)
```

Comment: Thx bro it worked ..... I am also having another trouble ... How can I move those images ? Load.place(x=2, y=2) isn't working

Comment: What exactly are you willing to do ? if placing an image i do recommend working with pannels and packs. In your code  img.place(x=,y=2) and not Load.place! is barely noticeable to your eyes, try with bigger values and you'll notice that it's properly working.